# Tabularx "auto" width?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I would like to create a table whose width should be the minimum possible (lines don't wrap). I see that `tabularx` wants a width parameter, is it possible to specify something like "auto", instead, for example, of `\linewidth`?

Comment: that is done by a simple `tabular` environment

Comment: @Herbert I guess that should be made the answer:-)

Comment: Do you *need* to use tabularx or are you fine with some other table?

Answer (score 12):

You don't need `tabularx` for your specifications. `tabular` is enough here.

```
\begin{tabular}{l r c}
foo & bar & and so on
\end{tabular}
```

is a tabular with a minimum width and default column separation width

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} l r c @{}}
foo & bar & and so on
\end{tabular}
```

is a tabular with no column separation on the left and right

```
{\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
\begin{tabular}{l r c}
foo & bar & and so on
\end{tabular}}
```

is a tabular with no column separation anyway

```
\begin{tabular}{l @{} r c }
foo & bar & and so on
\end{tabular}
```

is a tabular with no column separation between the first and second column

```
\begin{tabular}{l @{\hspace{5mm}} r c }
foo & bar & and so on
\end{tabular}
```

is a tabular with a column separation of 5mm between the first and second column

Comment: The question was about `tabularx`. You used `tabular`.

Comment: Sure, but there is no need for a `tabularx` for what the original poster asked for!

Comment: You don't know what he wants. You only know he wants a tabularx, but everything else is unknown. Let's pretend the OP is clever and knows why he wants to use a tabularx but on the other hand does not spam us with all the reasons he needs one and only asks one specific question. Which you unfortunately failed to answer.

Comment: @Mayou36: You should read the question, then you know what he/she wants ...

Comment: @Herbert, I agree that his first sentence seems to be general. But on one hand, he asks for a possible argument and on the other hand, the title says it all... But to be sure, I just asked the OP ;)

Comment: please discuss about tabularx because it is asked there. This wasnt aked for tabular.

Comment: The question is relevant because some software, such as STATA's savetex package uses tabularx to generate tables, and it lets you specify width as an option, with \linewidth as default. So no, using tabular is not an option

Comment: To add to this: The answers should be useful to everyone, not just the person who asked the question. I'm here because this is the top hit on google for "tabularx auto width," and I'm trying to solve this problem with a table that can't be made using the regular tabular environment. I guess I'll have to keep looking...